# Evitar objetos repetidos en la base de datos de django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Tengo una pagina que tiene un formulario donde la gente puede poner un nombre, y crearse un perfil. El problema es cuando varias personas intentan poner el mismo nombre, ya que da este error `get() returned more than one Person`

Lo que pretendo es evitar que se cree dos veces el mismo nombre en la base de datos.

Esta es la view, en la que he intentado que busque en la base de datos el nombre que se haya puesto, y si lo encuentra, que deje el proceso de añadir el nombre a la base de datos, pero por alguna razón no funciona:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PersonaForm(request.POST)
        elnombre=form.save(commit=False).nombre
        busqueda = ('a'+str(Persona.objects.filter(nombre=elnombre)))
        queryset = ('a'+'<QuerySet [<Persona: '+str(elnombre)+'>]>')
        if busqueda == sendmessage:
            #Aqui se haria algo para detener la creacion del perfil
        else:
            if form.is_valid():
                persona = form.save(commit=False)
                persona.save()
                return redirect('persona', nombre=persona.nombre)
    else:
        form = PersonaForm()

    return render(request, 'crush/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Entonces, ¿Como podría evitar que se cree el mismo objeto varias veces en la base de datos?

El modelo Persona:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False,)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.nombre

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.nombre
```

Comment: Hola, ¿de dónde sale `sendmessage`?, ¿por qué estás haciendo los queries de esa forma usando strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes usar [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists)

```
user = User.objects.filter(name='ImHarvol').exists()
```

si es `False`, el usuario no existe

Y en tu model Persona debes usar `unique=True`

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, unique=True)
```